# How to determine the number of Invitations per user in the last 30 days?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

my database has two tables related to this questions:

```
users: id, first_name, last_name, created_at
invitations: id, user_id
```

What I am trying to output is a list of all users created in the last 30 days and the number of invitations they sent out.. desired output from the query:

```
user.id | total_invitations
31 | 2
32 | 0
33 | 12
34 | 1
35 | 1
.....
```

Here's my work in progress query, what am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT u.id,
             u.first_name,
           u.last_name,
             u.invitation_approved_at,
       COUNT(i.id) AS Total
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN invitations i
     ON u.id = i.user_id
WHERE 
    i.type = 'email'
        AND i.revoked_at IS NULL
        AND u.invitation_approved_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    AND u.invitation_approved_at < curdate() - INTERVAL -7 DAY
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.invitation_approved_at;
```

ty

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Why do you think anything is wrong?

Comment: You just need to add `first_name` and `last_name` to your GROUP BY and you should be golden. IT would help to know RDBMS you are using though.

Comment: I guess you use mysql ?

Comment: mariadb is my db

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: Are you getting an error or incorrect results? It really looks fine as-is.

Comment: Just updated the query with the latest.. still trying to get this working.. The problem with the above is I am only getting output for users that sent 1 or more invitation .. it is not including those that have 0 invitations

Comment: `INTERVAL 7 DAY`

Comment: Your data structure doesn't match your query. Maybe you should give some sample data.

Comment: BTW left join is useless there, you are implying an inner join with WHERE (maybe add a NULL check there to provide Left Join) : WHERE i.id is null OR ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are restricting your `LEFT JOIN'd` table in your WHERE clause effectively turning it into an INNER JOIN. Instead:

```
SELECT u.id,
             u.first_name,
           u.last_name,
             u.invitation_approved_at,
       COUNT(i.id) AS Total
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN invitations i
     ON u.id = i.user_id
       AND i.type = 'email'
        AND i.revoked_at IS NULL
WHERE  u.invitation_approved_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    AND u.invitation_approved_at < curdate() - INTERVAL -7 DAY
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.invitation_approved_at;
```

Moving those two conditions to your `ON` clause causes those records to be filtered BEFORE the join occurs instead of AFTER.

I would also advocate for including your `first_name` and `last_name` field in your `GROUP BY` as every other RDBMS will error should a non-aggregated field not be present in your `GROUP BY` clause. I'm not sure if newer versions of MariaDB would throw an error, but newer versions of MySQL definitely will (versions earlier than 5.7 would happily run this as-is though):

```
 GROUP BY u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
```

Comment: that makes sense. thank you for helping me resolve and understand the issue